# is there a way to detect a press of a column header of a treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I want the content of a treeview to be ordered depending on what column header the user clicked.

I've already tried to use the treeview virtual events but pressing a header didn't fire an event even though it has a click and hover animation.

Comment: Pick one of [`[tkinter][treeview] sort`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5btkinter%5d%5btreeview%5d%20sort)

Answer (score 5):

I actually already found a solution. When assigning the column headers there's a kwarg for a command so the code could look like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk      # Tk
import tkinter.ttk as tkk # treeview

root = tk.Tk()

# create the Treeview
tv = ttk.Treeview(root)
tv['columns'] = ('a', 'b', 'c')
tv['show'] = 'headings' #remove "#0" column

# Add column headers and Click commands
tv.heading('a', text='header a', command=lambda: print('a is pressed!')
tv.heading('b', text='header b', command=lambda: print('b is pressed!')
tv.heading('c', text='header c', command=lambda: print('c is pressed!')
```

Comment: How about itterating heading? how do i handle callback function for that?

```for c in self.df.columns.tolist():
      self.tree.heading(c, text=c, anchor='w',
      command=lambda:
        print(c)
      )```

I expect print according collumn pressed, but when i execute it, it only print last value of var ```c``` whatever col i press.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MiaFenestro:
    def __init__(self, radiko):
        self.tabelo = ttk.Treeview(radiko, columns=("#0","#1","#2"), show="headings")

        self.tabelo.bind ('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.selektcxelo)

    def selektcxelo(self, event):
        zono = self.tabelo.identify("region", event.x, event.y)
        self.lakolumno = int(self.tabelo.identify_column(event.x)[1:])
        if zono == 'heading':
            print('Ĝi estas head '+str(self.lakolumno))
        else:
            print('Ĝi ne estas head')
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30836016)